# Type Hungarian special alphabets on Debian, ibus

Tags: debian, ibus

I am Vietnamese, I use ibus to type Vietnamese on my Debian. I just started to learn Hungarian and I need to type some Hungarian characters which I can't type with ibus-unikey, like <kbd>ë</kbd>, <kbd>ö</kbd>, <kbd>ő</kbd>, <kbd>ü</kbd> or <kbd>ű</kbd>.

Other characters like <kbd>á</kbd>, <kbd>ó</kbd>,... I can type with no problems as we have them in Vietnamese as well.

I added Hungarian to my ibus but I still can't figure out how to type those characters.

If you know how or if you know there are instructions somewhere, please let me know. I really appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure and use the `composeKey`:

**Under gnome Desktop** :

From the **system settings** choose **keyboard** >> **keyboard layouts** >>  **option** then Select **position of compose key** extend it and choose (eg: **Caps Lock**)

[image]

To get the accented character press :

[composeKey] + [accent character] + [letter]

e,g:

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> +  <kbd>"</kbd> +  <kbd>o</kbd> =  <kbd>ö</kbd>

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> +  <kbd>"</kbd> +  <kbd>u</kbd> =  <kbd>ü</kbd>

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> +  <kbd>"</kbd> +  <kbd>e</kbd> =  <kbd>ë</kbd>

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> +  <kbd>"</kbd> +  <kbd>i</kbd> =  <kbd>ï</kbd>

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> +  <kbd>~</kbd> +  <kbd>a</kbd> =  <kbd>ã</kbd>

**edit**:

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> +  <kbd>"</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> =  <kbd>Ö</kbd>

**Under Kde Desktop**

**system settings** >> **imput devices** >> **keyboard** >>  **Advanced** >> **configure keyboard option** >> **compose key position** extend it then make your choice.

Comment: Thank you it works! I have a small question. If I press [Compose] + ["] + [o] I will get ó. [Compose] + [Shift] + ["] + [o] I will get Ö. How do I get the lowercase of Ö ?

Comment: @HungTran i edit my answer

Comment: As a sidenote, you'll need
[compose] + [=] + [o]  → ő

Comment: @HungTran Re the lowercase of Ö  — the pre-defined key sequences are in `/usr/share/X11/locale/compose/*/Compose`